# Output label in UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I can link labels to ViewController.h in my main view. However, in the settings screen, the program won't let me output the label to the ViewController.h. Because of this, "testLabel" below, is marked as an undeclared identifier. I want the label to reflect whether the user is connected to the internet or not.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import "Reachability.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
    Reachability *internetReachableFoo;
}

- (IBAction)cameraButtonClicked:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *testLabel; //Not linked

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)testInternetConnection
{
    internetReachableFoo = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

    // Internet is reachable
    internetReachableFoo.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        // Update the UI on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            testLabel.text = @"YAY Intrawebs!!";
        });
    };

    // Internet is not reachable
    internetReachableFoo.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        // Update the UI on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            testLabel.text = @"Someone broke the internet";
        });
    };

    [internetReachableFoo startNotifier];
}
```

[image: Settings Screen]

Answer (score 0):

Have you connected the label in the storyboard?
Once that is done...you will have to reference the testLabel by

```
_testLabel
```

or

```
self.testLabel
```

May will have to make a weak reference to the label because if it is in a block.  Like this:

```
// Update the UI on the main thread
__block __weak ViewController *weakself = self;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    weakself.testLabel.text = @"YAY Intrawebs!!";
});
```

Comment: Thats the thing, when I right click from the story board, and drag the line over to ViewController.h, It won't let me make a connection.

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to connect to a UILabel and not a UITextView?

Comment: Yes, Do I need to create a different class for that specific UIViewController?

Comment: Make sure the UIViewController on the storyboard has a Custom Class of ViewController.